# Allocated memory seen on Task Manager

Tags: c++, memory-management

I want to allocate 1 GB of memory. Assuming int takes 4 bytes, to allocate 1 GB I need an array of 250000000 elements:

```
int main() { 
    string s;

    cout << "Program paused" << flush;
    getline(cin, s);
    int * p = new int[250000000]{};
    cout << "Program paused" << flush;
    getline(cin, s);
    delete [] p;
    cout << "Program paused" << flush;
    getline(cin, s);
}
```

Windows Task Manager show that my program uses 954 MB. Why is it less than 1 GB?

EDIT: The task manager also shows that OS reserved 979,100 MB of virtual memory for the process what is still less than 1 GB.

Comment: how about virtual memory part ? he probably show you just what is in RAM

Comment: Private active working set is 976,848 MB. How can I check the virtual memory?

Comment: The task manager  shows that OS reserved 979,100 MB of virtual memory for the process what is still less than 1 GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`250,000,000 bytes * 4` is **not** 1GB. Remember a Gigabyte ([more accurately, a Gibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)) is 1024 megabytes (mebibytes), and each mebibyte is 1024 kilobytes (kibibytes) which is 1024 bytes.

To allocate 1 GiB (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`) you want:

```
const size_t len = ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ) / sizeof(int); // 268,435,456 
int* p = new int[ len ]{};
```

Comment: @JohnZwinck Derp, gah - it's 4am here - hold on!

Comment: @JohnZwinck There, fixed! :D

Answer (score 2):

1 GB is 1024x1024x1024 bytes (by convention)

So 250000000 x 4 is less than 1GB.

So you are using (250000000 x 4) / (1024x1024) MB which is about 953 MB

Comment: Also if it bugs you that 1GB is not a billion bytes read up on Wikipedia about GiB (Gibibytes) vs GB Gigabytes